# How to serialize a DateTimeFormatter in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, serialization, rdd

I am using DateTimeFormatter in scala and now it is giving me trouble with a serialization.

Comment: Did you try initializing the DateTimeFormatter within your last map method as was also suggested as an option in the URL you provided?

Comment: Yes, the same error happens.

Comment: Can you include that code in your original question?

Comment: Yes, of course. I edited the question.

Comment: On which line is the error occurring? Is it when you initialize formatter, or when you initialize parsedDates?

Comment: I posted the whole error, but I think the problem is formatter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195290/discussion-between-jonathan-myers-and-lazar-gugleta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because the function is still being defined outside the scope of your map. Re-format how your map is operating to include the DateTimeFormatter being defined inside of map as follows:

```scala
val evega = concat.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(0)).groupByKey().map{case (k, v) => {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val parsedDates = v.map(sa => LocalDate.parse(sa(1), formatter))
    parsedDates.max.getDayOfYear - parsedDates.min.getDayOfYear
}}
```